# How to pass email receiver params in NodeJS to send email function with send grid service

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I added to my NodeJS API an endpoint to send an email, for now, is a simple function that sent an email hardcoded and I did it using Send Grid service. 
What I would like to achieve now is that I can pass the receiver email in the endpoint request and send the email.
Example of the endpoint `url/email/:email` 
the `:email` will be the receiver of the email. I would like to pass this param to my email function which will send there. But I stack as cannot understand how to pass the param inside the sen email like it is now my code.

What I tried so far:

Router

```
// POST email send
router.post("/email/:email", async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.params.email;
    try {
        const sent = await sendEmail(email);
        if (sent) {
            res.send({ message: "email sent successfully", status: 200 });
            console.log("Email sent");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
});

// Routes
module.exports = router;
```

Send email

```
const mailGenerator = new MailGen({
    theme: "salted",
    product: {
        name: "Awesome Movies",
        link: "http://example.com"
    }
});

const email = {
    body: {
        name: receiver here??,
        intro: "Welcome to the movie platform",
        action: {
            instructions:
                "Please click the button below to checkout new movies",
            button: {
                color: "#33b5e5",
                text: "New Movies Waiting For you",
                link: "http://example.com/"
            }
        }
    }
};

const emailTemplate = mailGenerator.generate(email);
require("fs").writeFileSync("preview.html", emailTemplate, "utf8");

const msg = {
    to: receiver here??,
    from: "jake@email.io",
    subject: "Testing email from NodeJS",
    html: emailTemplate
};

const sendEmail = () => {
    try {
        sgMail.setApiKey(sg_token);
        return sgMail.send(msg);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};

module.exports = { sendEmail };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sendEmail method not accept parameters. Add receiver on signature and use it

```
const sendEmail = (receiver) => {
    try {
        sgMail.setApiKey(sg_token);
        return sgMail.send({ ...msg, to: receiver });
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: And how I pass the receiver as in msg and in email section is telling me undefined in this way also? Can you please show a complete solution as like this seems something I'm missing

Comment: I resolved but can not pass the receiver to be also the name of the email part like
`body: { name: receiver }` this does not work

Comment: With something like getEmailData(..) (or more complex structure of "message builder") that enrich your message with receiver and other data (link of button, name, text, attachment....)